# How to Read a Pure FTPD log file?

Tags: ftp, pureftpd

I'm trying to analyze my FTP log to investigate some unauthorized access, but I can't make sense of some of the far right columns.

```
Thu Oct 01 00:13:55 2009 0 92.54.102.153 2547 /home/user1/public_html/index.html a _ o r user1 ftp 1 * c
Thu Oct 01 00:13:58 2009 0 77.252.189.148 2606 /home/user1/public_html/index.html a _ i r user1 ftp 1 * c
```

I can't find any documentation on how to read these logs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Here](http://www.castaglia.org/proftpd/doc/xferlog.html) is the website describing your log format. It has a good description of what every field in your log file means.

Comment: Awesome. I'm wondering if the proftpd and pureftpd log files are the same, or maybe I'm wrong about what's running on my server?

Comment: Your link was really hard to spot at the start there. It was exactly what I was after though. Thanks. =)